# Bevel is warping the surface

Tags: bevel

[image: Blender issue]

I've constantly been running into bevel issues, where instead of 'rounding' the selected edge, it is warping the surface, creating texture I do not want. I am currently using a Mac (shortcut I use for bevel is command+shift+b--command b does not do anything for me) and every tutorial I try out, I get stuck when it comes to rounding any corner or edge. Is there possibly a fix for this?

Comment: It looks a lot like you're actually beveling vertices, not the edge itself. Select an edge > Ctrl+B should do what you want. Ctrl+Shift+B is vertex bevel.

Comment: Thank you for responding! I tried using Command+B and all it appears to do is move the bevel line--nothing seems to be changing.

Comment: please share your file so that we can give a try: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5lY523mw" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5lY523mw/)

Comment: @moonboots I'm thinking it may be a keybinding issue, everything I see in online forums and other tutorials, Command+B seems to work appropriately for everyone else...

Comment: If you're having trouble getting a keybind to work, you can go into the system preferences and map it to something different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the moment you can't bevel the edge because you have an inner face, the edge is common to 3 faces and therefore Blender can't guess how to bevel, once the inner face deleted, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>B</kbd> should work:

[image]

If you have a problem of shortcut, you can open the *Preferences > Keymap* and type "bevel" in the search field, then redefine the shortcuts you want for this operation.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! I extruded that section and didn't think the face would make it warp like that. I have been literally stuck on this for months (noob, I know)!!!